# How to clear a bean field with Stripes

Tags: java, web-applications, stripes

In a JSP I have the following field:

```
<stripes:text name="email"/>
```

This field is in my action bean(snippet):

```
    public class CreateClaim implements ActionBean {

    private String email;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Resolution alc(){
        email = "poodle";
        return new ForwardResolution("aForward.jsp");
    }

}
```

In the alc() methos I am setting email to be null.  But when the pages renders the value of the email field is exactly as it was entered originally.
Is there a way of clearing this field once and event has triggered?

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the **population strategy** of the Stripes framework. By default it has a *Request first strategy* (due to backward compatibility with earlier versions), but I always change it to the [bean first population strategy](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/tag/BeanFirstPopulationStrategy.html).

Just edit the *web.xml* to add a init-param for your Stripes filter:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>PopulationStrategy.Class</param-name>
      <param-value>
        net.sourceforge.stripes.tag.BeanFirstPopulationStrategy
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
..etc...
```

Comment: Brilliant, the worked a treat.

I did manage a work around using flash scope and a redirect, but this must be the correct way to handle it.

Comment: I only use redirect after post requests, because it stops accidental double form submissions in case the browser back button is used. I all cases other cases the BeanFirstPopulationStrategy does its work.